# SQLITE3 python3.x class function is called twice

Tags: python, sqlite, multiple-value

I don't know why but every time I call a function it is called twice

```
    def nicks(self, user, nick=None, mode="get"):
            db = w.connect("bots.db")
            c = db.cursor()

            if mode == "create":
                    c.execute('delete from nicks where user like("%s")' % (user))
                    c.execute('insert into nicks(user, nick, time) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, nick, set_time))
                    db.commit()
            elif mode == "ginfo":
                    nick = "".join([n[1] for n in c.fetchall()])
                    time = "".join([t[2] for t in c.fetchall()])
                    try: return "NICK_SET: %s TIME_SET: %s" % (nick, formatTime(time))
                    except Exception as e: return "NICK_SET: Not Found TIME_SET: Not Found"
            elif mode == "get":
                    try:
                         print("MODE: %s" % mode)
                         c.execute('select * from nicks where user like("%s")' % (user))
                         #nick = "".join([us[2] for us in c.fetchall()])
                         return ''.join([us[2] for us in c.fetchall()])
                    except: return user
  print(nicks(user="user", nick="nick", mode="create"))
  print(nicks(user="user"))
  return_value: nick
  return_value: nick
```

the whole module can be found here http://yuribot.com/mod.txt

Comment: Errr, What's `nick`? And is `get` meant to be the `mode` and not the `nick`? It might help if you explain what you're trying to do...

Comment: sorry yes the "get" is the mode. The purpose of this function is to assign users nicks instead of their username. So when they use the bot they are called by whatever the user sets

Comment: Well in that case - you're passing `get` as the `nick` parameter - so is your second function (minus the typo) meant to be `nicks('user')` or possibly `nicks('user', mode='get')` ?

Comment: print(nicks(user="user", nick="nick", mode="create")) #creates the nick                        print(nicks(user="user")) #grabs the nick

Comment: i have it calling correctly in the module as far printing but made errors posting it the module is here http://yuribot.com/mod.txt

Comment: You still didn't fix the `nick`->`nicks` typo, or explain where the `return_value: nick` lines come from. To give people the best possible chance to help, you have to provide the *exact* code that you are *actually* using. Also, there are surely better values to test with than `nick="nick"`. You are as likely to be confusing yourself as you are to be confusing us at this point.

Comment: Your delete statement is dangerous. Wait until a user called `%` comes along... Also, don't use string formatting to build queries, pass your arguments as [`parameters`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) tuple, and don't escape them yourself, leave that to the library.